# PHP update adds new record with an id of 0

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my first time so please be patient with me.
I have tried and tried without success!
My database has 7 fields with the last one being 'id' as key and auto increment
I am trying to update one or all of the fields in 1 record only.
However I just get a new record with all previous data except id is incremented by 1.
This is my code:

```
<?php
$error = '';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){ // If session is not set then    redirect to Login Page
header("Location:Login.php");  
}

// grab connection code
$login_id = $_SESSION['login_id'];

include "connection.php";

$query = "SELECT * FROM bvoa_login WHERE id = '$login_id'";

// get result
$result = $conn->query($query);

//create array of result
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
// set existing data into variables
$curr_name = $row["name"];
$curr_username = $row["username"];
$curr_email = $row["email"];
$curr_property_no = $row["property_no"];    
$curr_website = $row["website"];    

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['email'])
        && !empty($_POST['new_password']) && !empty($_POST[  'password_confirm']) && !empty($_POST['location']) && !empty($_POST['real_name'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $real_name = $_POST['real_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $new_password = $_POST['new_password'];
        $password_confirm = $_POST['password_confirm'];
        $location = $_POST['location'];
        $website = $_POST['website'];

        // compare passwords...
        if (strcmp($new_password, $password_confirm) == 0){
            $password_hash = sha1($new_password);
            $query = "UPDATE `bvoa_login` SET `username`='$username' WHERE `id`='$login_id'";
            $result = $conn->query($query);
        }else{
            $error = "Passwords do not match.";     
    }
    }else{  
    $error = "You must enter all fields to continue.";
    }
$conn->close();
}
?>
```

OK I have adjusted the script so it only has 1 query. The database has 1 record with an id of 1. I still adds another record with no entry in the id field.

```
<?php
$error = '';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){ // If session is not set then redirect to Login Page
    header("Location:Login.php");  
}

// grab connection code
$login_id = $_SESSION['login_id'];

include "connection.php";


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['email'])
        && !empty($_POST['new_password']) && !empty($_POST[  'password_confirm']) && !empty($_POST['location']) && !empty($_POST['real_name'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
    $real_name = $_POST['real_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $new_password = $_POST['new_password'];
    $password_confirm = $_POST['password_confirm'];
        $location = $_POST['location'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];

    // compare passwords...
    if (strcmp($new_password, $password_confirm) == 0){
        $password_hash = sha1($new_password);
        $query = "UPDATE `bvoa_login` SET `username`='$username' WHERE `id`='$login_id'";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
    }else{
        $error = "Passwords do not match.";     
    }
}else{  
$error = "You must enter all fields to continue.";
}
$conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: The code in your question doesn't make much sense. For one you create a lot of variables you don't use. Why are they there? You don't check the result of the first select query, you should. And you are not using binding in your update query. Are you using PDO? See: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: This script is from a 'change profile page'. The first set are the original details that are loaded into the form. The next set are the new details. At the moment I am trying to update the username. When that works I will add the others. Checks and security will be added once I have it working. But at the moment this query is adding a new record with an id of 0 (zero). I will have to read up on PDO.

Comment: Binding is also possible in MySQLi. For questions it's better to use only code that is relevant to the question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve This way you are also sure the problem you have is actually present in the code in your question. The reason there is no response to your question is that your code has a `SELECT` and `UPDATE` query, but no `INSERT` query. You cannot get a new row without the latter. As I said: the code doesn't make much sense. Please don't treat checks and security as an afterthought, they are of paramount importance.

Comment: Your WHERE clause doesn't match any existing row, that's why it adds a new row. Print out $login_id and see if it matches the existing id

Comment: The $login_id is set by the login page. When I add echo $login_id; it returns '1' The database has 1 row with7 fields the last one being 'id' = 1. This script adds a new row with an id = empty. But where is the UPDATE picking up the other field info from?

Answer (score 0):

Solved - very stupid mistake - the 'profile.php' page was a duplicate of 'register.php' and I forgot to change the form action so it was calling the wrong page - DUHHH!!!   Thank to all who took time to comment.